# Can I avoid catch block in Java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Inside a method, I use a Scanner to read text inside a file. This file doesn't always exist, and if it doesn't, I want simply to do nothing (i.e. no scan).
Of course I could use a try/catch like this:

```
String data = null;
try
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(folder + "file.txt"));
    data=scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
}
```

My question is what can I do to avoid the try/catch? Because I don't like local variable unused. I was thinking of something like:

```
String data = null;
File file_txt = new File(folder + "file.txt");
if (file_txt.exists())
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file_txt);
    data=scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
}
```

But of course with this I get an error in Netbeans and I can't build my project...

Comment: It's a checked exception that you must handle - it's a reminder by the compiler to the programmers to handle unsafe operations because they can cause at any time even though the application is very-well coded (`FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`). Unchecked exceptions on the other hand are caused because of bad coding practice and cannot be reminded of by the compiler and should be coded well rather than just handling them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, It's checked exception. [try](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) must be followed with either [catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block and/or [finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block. There are two method for handling checked exception.

**Method 1 : Either wrap your code using `try/catch/finally`**

**Option 1**

```
try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(folder + "file.txt"));
    data=scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
   System.out.println("Caught " + ex);
}
```

**Option 2**

```
try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(folder + "file.txt"));
    data=scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();

}
finally
{ 
      System.out.println("Finally ");
}
```

**Option 3**

```
    try{ 
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(folder + "file.txt"));
     data=scan.nextLine();
     scan.close();
     }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
          System.out.println("Caught " + ex );
     }finally{
          System.out.println("Finally ");
     }
```

**Method 2: Throw exception using `throw` and list all the exception with `throws` clause.**

```
    class ThrowsDemo {

    static void throwOne() throws IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("Inside throwOne.");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            throwOne();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught " + e);
        }
    }
    }
```

**Note :** Checked Exception means Compiler force you to write something to handle this error/exception. So, AFAIK, there is no any alternative for checked exception handling except above method.

Comment: See the post below please, I know about throw, it's just a little more complex. I basically want to avoid the exception, maybe with something different?

Comment: you cannot avoid exception, you can only handle them.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I wanted to know. By the way, Option 2 doesn't work. And technically yes, I avoid the exception with the if, because if the file doesn't exist, the code is not executed, so there is no exception (tested). I guess the compiler is not that smart...

Comment: @user1904496  i believe, for you Method 2 is suitable. Just go through.

Comment: I just tested it, and I still have an error that says I have an unreported exception.

Comment: No I was talking about Option 2 :) About method 2, as I said below, it is just as fine as the empty catch, because even if I use another method for optional file, I will still have a bunch of useless try/catch when I call this method. And I do call it a lot, so in my case it's worse. I guess I should think differently.

Comment: the purpose of using catch to display your customize error to your user instead of `Unreported exception java.io.FileNotFound exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown.` type of error. If you are saying Option 1 is working and Option 2 is not. Then, i would say, it can't be possible. Either both will show error or none.

Comment: You're probably right. Do you know if there is any macro to tell the compiler that I don't care about FileNotFound? I mean transform this checked exception into unchecked one?

Comment: @user1904496 hahahaha.... dude, this is the only way. By using try/catch, we are handling this checked exception in our way. First of all you need to know, what is the difference between checked and unchecked, follow this link http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129

Answer (score 2):

`FileNotFoundException` is checked exception, Due to [catch or specify behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html), you need to either catch (or) specify it in throws clause of method declaration.

Comment: I know about throw, but I handle the same error in the same method because there are files that are compulsory. I could create a method which only takes care of optional files, but that's just moving the problem. I was more thinking of an alternative where there is no need of catch.

Comment: @user1904496: I got your point, but unfortunately there is no other way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
   catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
   {
       // create a log entry about ex
   }
```

Comment: catch(FileNotFoundException) does not work in Java. And I don't want to create a log entry because this is perfectly normal (I mean the fact that the file could not exist)!